# Which processes in the autoconf and automake flowchart are performed by who and when?

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

In the flowchart of autoconf and automake from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automake , there are several processes

- autoscan
- alocal
- autoheader
- autoconf
- automake
- configure
- make

Which processes are performed

- by a user of a software program after he downloaded the distribution of the software program
- by the party who creates the distribution of the software program from its source code (and who is likely the author of the software program)?

I ask this question, because I remember that after I, as a user of some software program, downloaded its source distribution, the commands I ran to build an executable from the source distribution were `autoconf`, `./configure`, and `make`. So I guess that the other processes in the flowchart had been performed during the creation of the distribution by the author of the software program. Am I correct?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Which processes are performed by a user of a software program after he downloaded the distribution of the software program

It depends on what you want to do.  Lots of people are only after the basic build commands to configure, build, and install the software package:

```
# ./configure; make; make install
```

and you'll not need to invoke `autoreconf`, `autoconf`, `automake` in those cases, even if you're patching source.  If the modifications are extensive enough to need to modify `configure.ac` or `Makefile.am` files, then *maybe* the other tools will need to be invoked.  Often `configure` is smart enough to automatically invoke them on your behalf.

`autoscan` is really only useful for for porting your software package to the GNU Build System.  The same for `autoheader`.  Once you've got a basic `configure.ac` and `config.h.in` you're not going to be needing those tools again.  These tools are nice, but not *required* to produce the aforementioned files.

> Which processes are performed by the party who creates the distribution of the software program from its source code (and who is likely the author of the software program)?

If you have some kind of automated software build, I'd imagine it'd invoke `autoreconf -fvi` and possibly a few other steps after a fresh checkout from a VCS.  That's why there are `bootstrap.sh` or `autogen.sh` scripts.  That basically invokes `aclocal`, `autoconf` and `automake` to write `configure`.  Then basically `configure; make distcheck;` to make the distribution.