# Are these inputs to `autoheader`, `autoscan`, `automake` and `make`?

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

I am comparing

- the flowchart of autoconf and automake from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automake ,
- Figure 1 - File Input/Output Graph in http://www.seul.org/docs/autotut/

Are the following differences between them normal? Which one is correct?

- Which is the input to `autoheader` and `autoscan`, `configure.ac` or `configure.in`?
- For inputs to `automake`, are `configure.ac` and `config.h.in` its inputs?
- For inputs to `make`, is `config.h` its input?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Which is the input to autoheader and autoscan, configure.ac or configure.in?

`configure.in` is a deprecated name for `configure.ac`, but are otherwise equal.

> For inputs to automake, are configure.ac and config.h.in its inputs?

`automake` will ignore `config.h.in` altogether, but it *will* need `configure.ac` (or `.in`) to figure out which options you're requesting.

> For inputs to make, is config.h its input?

`make` will execute the commands defined in `Makefile`; `config.h` is an input to some of those commands because it is included by the source files. It might or might not be installed, and so be a direct input to `make` commands, but it really shouldn't.

Comment: thanks. if `automake` will ignore `config.h.in`, then why does the flowchart in wikipedia shows `config.h.in` as an input to `automake`?

Comment: I assume because it's wrong :) I have not drawn one such diagram in a while, and never published one before, maybe I should add one to Autotools Mythbuster (autotools.io) so that it can be referenced from Wikipedia.

Comment: thanks. Then `config.h.in` is used only by `configure`. A related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437657/which-processes-in-the-autoconf-and-automake-flowchart-are-performed-by-who-and